# Does IE10 recognize the sibling combinator when triggered via :active?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I want to apply CSS to a sibling div when an a link is :active

```
.navigation-menu:active ~ .container-menu,
    left: 0;
}
```

I know IE9 and below don't support this but does IE10?

Comment: what is stopping you from trying that out? wouldn't it have taken about as long as it took to post this question here?

Comment: @GungFoo not everyone has access to IE 10 and sibling & pseudo-class support is something I think should be checked in a real browser. Think it's a fair enough question...

Comment: I agree that it might be a fair enough question. But if you care enough to ask that question you kinda have to have IE10, otherwise there seems little point in knowing the answer. Which to me made this debate just enter an endless loop

Comment: @GungFoo I don't have access to IE10. I've searched around for an answer but couldn't find one. I've asked a question on a Q&A site. No harm in that. I'm allowed to have knowledge without having to implement anything. No need for the negative attitude.

Comment: Sorry if my attitude came about as negative. I was merely expressing my wonderment about you wanting to know a details about IE10 without having it available for either use or further testing. I don't see how an answer helps you if you are not using IE10 and if you do need IE10, will you ask a question here everytime you need to test something on it? :P It just doesn't sound efficient, sorry if that makes you upset.

Comment: I'm not upset but your initial comments are pointless as you have no knowledge of what I need the information for. Its Boolean, either you have a constructive answer and reply with that or you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't work in IE10. I tested with the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uYsXP/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="navigation-menu">Click me</a>
    <div class="container-menu">Bacon!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation-menu:active ~ .container-menu {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the general sibling selector with a pseudo class, you run into some bugs, but this can be fixed.  Refer to this article:

http://css-tricks.com/webkit-sibling-bug/

```
body { -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s; }
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix { from { padding: 0; } to { padding: 0; } }
```

This should work IE8+

Comment: That is for a specific webkit bug. I was under the impression that triggering CSS on a sibling via :active just didn't work in IE9 and below?

Comment: The other thing I was going to suggest is Modernizr.  It detects if the browser your user is on has functionality for the features you select, and if not, uses a jQuery backup.  There might be a learning curve if you're not already familiar with javascript, but it is definitely the future.  For example, media queries do not work in IE 8, but with modernizr, they do.

Comment: Just to clarify Modernizr just tests for the availability of media queries support, it doesn't make them work. You'd need something like respond.js for that.

Comment: Modernizr provides a script loader so you can pull in polyfills to backfill functionality in old browsers.  Respond.js, I believe, is only a polyfill for media queries. The beauty of modernizr is that polyfills are only loaded if they *need* to be loaded.  Which means fast load times if they aren't needed.  However, I have not yet implemented these so I'm no expert, but that is what I have read so far.

Comment: Is there any speed difference between loading respond.js via Modernizer or loading it with a conditional IE statement within the HTML?

Comment: No idea, I'm not there yet!

Answer (score 0):

The :active state of a child is not propagated down from the parent (at least in IE 10)

There's a JS workaround posted on this SO answer: [Make a whole div clickable with working :active css rule in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827534/make-a-whole-div-clickable-with-working-active-css-rule-in-ie10/10885417#10885417)

---

It's worth noting that the *IE dev team has classified* this issue as `won't fix`

> Propagating the active state to ancestor elements can significantly
>   degrade the responsiveness of web pages due to the large number of
>   elements that may be impacted by the state change. As a result, this
>   makes interactive controls feel sluggish to an end user, particularly
>   in touch interaction where tiny delays are easily perceptible.

**source:** https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/757765/ie10-active-psuedo-class-should-be-triggered-by-child-elements-too