# css3 :active trigger not working in IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

Hi am trying to figure out on why in css3 :active or :hover animation dont trigger it works on every other browser. ive wrapped the code into this fiddle
please help me am stuck on this since the past 2 days

Comment: sorry heres the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LVYhD/

Answer (score 0):

in css3 have fix more no of cross browser problem.each browser have a different future.following keywords are using work on all the browser.
 Supported by Internet Explorer with the prefix -ms-
    Supported by Firefox with the prefix -moz-
    Supported by Google Chrome with the prefix -webkit-
    Supported by Safari with the prefix -webkit-
    Supported by Opera with the prefix -o-

Comment: that's not a problem which I am facing here. The animation would work if I don't give it ":active" or ":hover". Is there a compatibility issue that these states wont work on IE9-10

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using `:active` which has an issue in IE (verified in IE 10)

> From what I can gather, this is currently not possible as the :active
>   state of a child is not propagated up to the parent div. Both Internet
>   Explorer 10 and Opera 11.64 failed to propagate the :active state up
>   to the parent when testing with div elements.

**source:** [Make a whole div clickable with working :active css rule in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827534/make-a-whole-div-clickable-with-working-active-css-rule-in-ie10)